# Windows Explorer doesn't show updated names when changing capitalization (multiple files via script)

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, rename, batch-rename

If I have 5 or more files in a Windows Explorer folder and I rename them with a script that only changes capitalization, Explorer doesn't automatically "refresh" and show the new names in my open Explorer window. It will refresh automatically if I only rename 1 to 4 files or if I change the letters in the name to something else.

I have to manually press "F5" with the open Explorer window to see the new names. Is there a way I can make Explorer or Windows 10 refresh the directory automatically in a script so I don't have to press F5?

Here is an example batch file (rename.bat)

```
ren  file_important_stuff_1.txt  File_Important_Stuff_1.txt
ren  file_important_stuff_2.txt  File_Important_Stuff_2.txt
ren  file_important_stuff_3.txt  File_Important_Stuff_3.txt
ren  file_important_stuff_4.txt  File_Important_Stuff_4.txt
ren  file_important_stuff_5.txt  File_Important_Stuff_5.txt
```

It also fails to work with a simple Python script:

```
import os

for x in range(1,6):
    fileNameOld = "file_important_stuff_" + str(x) + ".txt"
    fileNameNew = "File_Important_Stuff_" + str(x) + ".txt"
    os.rename(fileNameOld,fileNameNew)
```

Here's a picture of the directory with files:

[image]

Comment: Explorer is not modifiable - you will need to keep on pressing F5.

Comment: I'm hoping for a workaround solution--some way of telling Explorer to refresh programmatically (it can be Powershell or batch or something). I can get Explorer to refresh if I move the files to another directory, put a wait for 2 seconds in the script, and then move them back, for example. But that's not really feasible for my problem (I don't want to have a 2-second delay).

Comment: @PaulK.Doesn't renaming "foo" to "bar" and (without any delay) from "bar" to "Foo" work?

Comment: It does not unfortunately. You can take any steps in between renaming `foo` to `Foo` and it won't recognize the change. You can move `foo` to another folder, change to `bar` and then to `Foo` and move it back and as long as it's relatively "instant" (<2 seconds), Explorer will not see the change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A script like this could help you:

```
$windows = $(New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).Windows()
$windows  | ? { $_.FullName -eq "C:\Windows\explorer.exe" -and $_.LocationURL -match "$path$" } | % { $_.Refresh() }
```

Breakdown:

- `$(New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).Windows()` - creates COM object for Explorer/IE and gets their active windows
- `$_.FullName -eq "C:\Windows\explorer.exe"` - condition to filter only `explorer.exe` windows in `Where-Object` (`?`) - this can very likely be skipped by almost all Windows 10+ users
- `$_.LocationURL -match "$path$"` - matches your path (that you can pass e.g. as a script param) with location URL. Some paths may need to be processed before getting matched as from what I noticed e.g. spaces are converted to `%20` in that field, I couldn't quickly find what the full encoding method is though. `$` at the end makes sure the URL ends with your path. You could skip this and just refresh all the Explorer windows.
- `$_.Refresh()` - refreshes filtered windows in `Foreach-Object` (`%`)

This will only work with default behaviour of Explorer though from what I see (it doesn't e.g. see additional [QTTabBar](http://qttabbar.wikidot.com/) tabs).

Comment: +1 for not offering a `SendKeys` solution! :D

Comment: Actually, with the demise of IE, you don't need to filter on `explorer.exe` anymore....

Comment: I doubt anyone uses it even if it's launchable in Win 10, so yea, the condition can likely be skipped.

Comment: Yep, this worked beautifully! Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much. I appreciate the detailed explanation as well.

Comment: @KeithMiller Unless you're some corporation that has some old internal software that works with IE but neither Egde, Firefox, or Chrome. Yes, those exist. Guess how I know.